# JMeter test of servlet flow

Tags: java, servlets, jmeter, stress-testing

I'm designing a stress test of a servlet, basically I send two options in the query params, the client ID and INPUT, I need to stress this servlet but i need it to do it dynamically because depending on the client ID and the input the result might be different (basically is a flow with a menu and options)

this is what the servlet returns(structure):

```
<menu>
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <menuOptions>
    <message>
      <option>1. Info</option>
    </message>
    <message>
      <option>2. Availability</option>
    </message>
  </menuOptions>
</menu>
```

So I wonder is there is any way to call the servlet and check the response to see is there are menu options and if so send any option with the same client ID in a repetitive way so it can be stressed, I was doing it with only a HTTP request and loading the ID clients for a CSV but the list it's about 1 million so in order to send a request for the very same number it has to loop all the cilents first and by that time the session for that client has already expired.

So I need something like a look inside each HTTP request to check, call again until the client has not options.

let me elaborate a full example below:

1. I use this URL for the first time `http://localhost:8080/Integration/menu?ID=123`

so the system returns:

```
<menu>
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <menuOptions>
    <message>
      <option>1. Info</option>
    </message>
    <message>
      <option>2. Availability</option>
    </message>
  </menuOptions>
</menu>
```

2. So if i want to choose any of the two options from the previous response, I need to send either 1 or 2 as an input, let's say I choose the first one

   http://localhost:8080/Integration/menu?ID=123&input=1

So the system returns:

```
<menu>
  <title>1. Info</title>
  <menuOptions>
    <message>
      <option>1. Client information</option>
    </message>
    <message>
      <option>2. Account Information</option>
    </message>
  </menuOptions>
</menu>
```

3. So let's say I choose the second one now

   http://localhost:8080/Integration/menu?ID=123&input=2

So the system returns:

```
<menu>
  <title>The account is activated</title>
  <menuOptions/>
</menu>
```

4. So at this point I can't send more optiones, because there are not available.

That's basically what I need to test dynamically in Jmeter, since all the menus are dynamic and can change for any user, also the fact I want to test the flow for one user at the same time, because as I said before now it loops all the clients first

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) which can automatically handle underlying components so you won't have to code complex logic manually, check out [Poll Example](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#poll_example) for reference implementation.

If it doesn't match your scenario try elaborating your question and explicitly let us know what you are trying to achieve. Also take a look into other [JMeter PreProcessors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/quick-guide-jmeter-preprocessors), especially scripting-based ones like [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), this way you will get extreme flexibility

Comment: I just edited my asnwer to give a more elaborated example of what I need to do @Dmitri